# Setting up gitweb/apache2

Tags: server, git, apache2

I have recently began storing code, that I write on a local server I have at home.

I was hoping to start a gitweb instance at home so I can see commits and track progress with my other team mates.

I have tried server tutorials online with no luck. I would like gitweb to be accessed by `example.com/git`

I would like my code to be place in `/code/git`

I would appreciate any help! Please try to be explicit as possible, because I clearly dont know what i am doing. I have read tons of articles.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **gitweb part:**

You have to install the package gitweb with `sudo apt-get install gitweb`

Then you have to edit the apache gitweb config file

```
$EDITOR /etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb
```

change the line `Alias /gitweb /usr/share/gitweb`
to

```
Alias /git /usr/share/gitweb
```

open the `/etc/gitweb.conf` file:

you have to change the line
`$projectroot ".."` to
`$projectroot "/code/git"`

and change any other line containing `/gitweb` to `/git`
for example

```
$stylesheet = "/gitweb/gitweb.css";
```

to

```
$stylesheet = "/git/gitweb.css";
```

then reload you apache webserver with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 horse-reload`

The **GIT part** itself:

**I STRONGLY recommend the use of gitosis** (http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)

**REMEMBER** if you **use gitosis** the line `$projectroot` in `/etc/gitweb.conf` has to be

```
$projectroot = "/home/git/repositories/";
```

You can find detailed information on howto setup gitosis at
http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

describing the full gitosis setup is too long for this answer.

If you need more help on gitosis drop me a comment

To fix apache permission problems, it might be necessary to do:

```
adduser www-data git
chgrp -R git /home/git/repositories
```

Comment: whats the difference between git and gitosis.

Comment: gitosis is a script to setup secure git hosting. (authenticate users with ssh and stuff.) its pretty straigt forward with a special git repository which contains a config. In this config you can configure the other git repositories

Comment: that is interesting to me. could you modify your answer to include gitosis setup?

Comment: http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way  is very detailed ( i used it for myself). If you experience a problem at one step, write me a comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to setup `gitweb` on Ubuntu 14.04 - with SSL and authentication of system users with `pwauth`. By default, `gitweb` uses a `/etc/gitweb.conf`, which expects `git` projects in `/var/lib/git`.

So I tried to put my `git` repos in here, so in this example we don't have to change `/etc/gitweb.conf` - my `/var/lib/git` looks like this:

```
$ ls -la /var/lib/git/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  3 root          root          4096 Apr  9 16:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 75 root          root          4096 Apr  7 17:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myuser        myuser        28 Apr  9 16:01 gitweb.cgi -> /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
drwxrwsr-x  7 myuser        www-data      4096 Apr 10 17:50 testrepo.git
```

So, beside your repos, you would need to symlink `/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi` in this directory too...

Then, you can use the following as `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitw-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    HeaderName HEADER
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-gw.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-gw.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
      # old style:
      AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
      SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
      # new style:
      #DefineExternalAuth pwauth pipe /usr/sbin/pwauth
    </IfModule>

    # as more specific, /gitweb/static should go first
    Alias /gitweb/static /usr/share/gitweb/static
    Alias /gitweb /var/lib/git
    # gitweb.cgi alias is no dice - symlink is needed:
    Alias gitweb.cgi /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
    <Directory /var/lib/git>
      Options +FollowSymlinks +ExecCGI
      SSLRequireSSL
      AuthType basic
      AuthName "Private git repository"
      AuthBasicProvider external
      AuthExternal pwauth
      Require valid-user
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
      DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/git-core/">
      SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/lib/git
      SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
      Options +ExecCGI
      SSLRequireSSL
      AuthType basic
      AuthName "Private git repository"
      AuthBasicProvider external
      AuthExternal pwauth
      Require valid-user
    </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And finally you can do:

```
# not sure if also `fcgid auth_digest` are needed:
sudo a2enmod ssl cgi alias env rewrite
sudo a2ensite gitw-ssl.conf
# if not `reload`, use `restart`:
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After this, `gitweb` should be available on `https://localhost/gitweb/` (for instance, `https://localhost/gitweb/?p=testrepo.git;a=summary`); and you should be able to clone (in case of a self-signed SSL certificate) with:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git clone https://myuser@localhost/git/testrepo.git
```